# Kivymd package crashes every time

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, packaging, kivymd, buildozer

I am working with both kivy and kivymd. Now I am trying make an apk file that can be installed on Android. And I made it using Buildozer.

After installing, when I open the application it just show the splash screen and then crashesh..

I can not find out the problem. Please help me.

Searching on internet I have tried many combination of "requirement". I don't think the problem is in requirement. Morever, I have checked the code. It is nothing but a dummy, just to check if I can use buildozer or not.

Comment: How to fix a shader bug on an android device - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD#how-to-fix-a-shader-bug-on-an-android-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  After days of trying different things, here's what I think the problem is:
https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/README.md#how-to-fix-a-shader-bug-on-an-android-device

Seems the latest versions of kivy and kivymd have a bug on Android (?) that can be solved by using the latest development versions of kivy and kivymd.

So with your virtual environment activated, do:

```
pip3 uninstall kivy
pip3 uninstall kivymd
```

then:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
pip3 install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

and replace your kivy and kivymd requirements in buildozer.spec with:

```
requirements = kivy==master, https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

To add to the fun, I can't get the latest development versions of kivy and kivymd to run on Ubuntu.  But they compiled to an APK successfully and on my phone the app doesn't crash.

To go back to developing on your computer, you'll have to uninstall kivy and kivymd (as above) and reinstall:

```
pip3 install kivy
pip3 install kivymd
```

Comment: Should not i add pillow and sdl2.ttf to my requirements?

Comment: @SaikatIslam Add whatever python packages your app needs.  I am having success with Buildozer using the Kivy and KivyMD packages above along with pillow,pygments,cffi.  You can also try (with your virtual environment activated) `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to check what packages your app is using.